# etur$post ajax ошибка в запросе

Tags: php, ajax, post

Имеются данные , представленный в виде XML :

```
function load($option){
    $xml_string =<<<XML
<city>
  <client>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Moscow</name>
      <mail>moscow@moscow.ru</mail>
      <phone>988998989</phone>
  </client>
  <client>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Sankt-Peterburg</name>
      <mail>xabarovsk@mail.ru</mail>
      <phone>99989998</phone>
  </client>
</city>
XML;
    //simplexml_load_file
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach ($xml->children() as $city) {
        if (strtolower($city->name) == strtolower($option) ) return $city;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['value'])){xbnf
    var_dump($_POST);
    $value = json_encode(load($_POST['value']));
     return $value;
}
```

на странице имеется select ,для выбора города

```
<select id="select_city" "> 
<optionvalue="moscow">Москва</option>
<option value="sankt-peterburg">Санкт-петербург</option>
</select>
```

Post (ajax) запрос :

```
$('#select_city').change(function() {
    var value= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: value,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success :function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#phone').html(result[0]);
            }
    })
```

и поля вывода в виде

```
 <p id="phone"><? php echo isset($value->phone) ?  $value->cite : "Москва"; ?></p>
```

Переменная $value  объявлена в виде global $value; значение переменной задается во время загрузки документа

Post запрос отправляется ,но ничего не возвращает , подскажите в чем я ошибся. С новым годом.

Отредактировав ajax подобным образом :

```
        $('#select_city').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: value,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',

                callbackParameter: 'callback',
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function (json) {
                    alert('success')
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('error')
                }

            })
        })
```

получаю вывод alern(error) (модальное окно)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51308/discussion-on-question-by-konstantin-maslov-eturpost-ajax---).

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем заработало следующим образом :

```
            $('#select_city').change(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {value: value},

                    callbackParameter: 'callback',
                    timeout: 10000,
                    success: function (value) {
                        alert()
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                    },
                })
            })
```

да и в файле test.php используем  echo  вместо return. Всем спасибо. С новым годом